# Using 2 connections in mongoose in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, connection-string

I want to use 2 or more different databases simultaneously, these 2 connections have different properties. And according to database selection data should be displayed. Its dynamic db switch in mongoose if anyone have any idea please help.

Lets say there is a model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Promise = require("bluebird");

mongoose.Promise = Promise;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var uomSchema = new Schema({
    uom: {
        type: String,
        required: [
            true,
            "Please enter valid uom"
        ],
        elementType: "TEXT",
        elementText: "Unit Of Measure",
        placeholder: ""
    }
}, { strict: false });
var uom = mongoose.model('uom', uomSchema);
```

module.exports = uom;

so here it creates model over default connection `foo`, so if there is another connection `bar` and over that db needs to create same model to operate over data, how is that possible ?

[mongoose-glue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-glue) provide somewhat similar solution, but not exact that I want

Answer (score 0):

Maintain one json file in that   { "db1":"asas" , "db2":"xczc" } and while connecting to db fetch db name from this json file as 
var conUrl = config.db1 OR db2 as per your condition

Comment: Thats okay, but that doesn't work actually mongoose need to switch from one db to another.

Comment: what exactly is your requirement?